# Should i use [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()] and then look for whitespace in the function, or use [ValidateScript(...)]?

Tags: powershell, parameters, attributes

Because in PowerShell there is no

```
[ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()]
```

Parameter attribute, is it better to use

```
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
```

as the parameter attribute, then look for whitespace inside the function, or should i use

```
[ValidateScript({ -not ([String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)) })]
```

as the parameter attribute.

im not sure what the NotNullOrEmpty attribute is really good for, because 99% of time, i don't want this to ever work:

```
My-Cmdlet -ParameterName " "
```

but because " " is still a string, it will pass the NotNullOrEmpty attribute.

Comment: PowerShell 7.4 introduces [ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace] (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/pull/9664)

Answer (score 8):

The `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]` is good for doing exactly what it says it will.

To answer your first question, I would use the `[ValidateScript(...)]` method you outlined.

One thing to keep in mind is that the error message for `[ValidateScript()]` is usually terrible and doesn't help the end user. As a workaround, you can do this:

```powershell
[ValidateScript( { 
    ![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -or throw 'Your string is null or contains whitespace' 
} )]
```

You can also include an exception class in the throw like:

```powershell
throw [System.ArgumentException]'Blah blah whitespace'
```

### Why the `-or throw` syntax works

Boolean operators in PowerShell work like many other languages in that they do "shortcutting". They stop evaluating the expression as soon as the outcome is definite. So for `$false -and $(sleep -min 10)` it doesn't take 10 minutes, because the second expr is never evaluated.

Similarly, `$true -or $(something)` will not evaluate the second, because it will always be true if the first expression is true.

So in this case it's similar. `ValidateScript` needs a bool. If the condition we care about is true, it will stop there. If it's not, the second expression is evaluated, and since that's a `throw` it will just fail, but in this case you can control the failure message (and exception class if you want).

Comment: I'm getting "You must provide a value expression following the '-or' operator." in PowerShell Core 7.4.1 inside VS Code. I like the concise format but I had to switch to @RoadRunner's syntax.

Comment: @JeffHumphreys thanks, I think you need to wrap the `throw` in `() or `$()`, if that works then I will edit the answer

Comment: Thanks @RoadRunner, I tried (), $(), ${}, {}. I thought it might be an issue with PowerShell Extension VS Code, so I tried the ISE with PS 5, and the PS 7 console, different errors but no luck.
    function Test-ValidateScriptThrow{
    param(
        [ValidateScript( { 
            ![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) -or (throw 'Your string is null or contains whitespace')
        } )]
    )
    }

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround would be to just [`Trim()`](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html) the whitespace and call `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()` inside `[ValidateScript()]`:

```
[ValidateScript({
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Trim()))
    {
        throw "Your string is null or empty."
    } else {
        $true
    }
})]
```

Which will handle all `$null`, `""` and `" "` cases, since all whitespace `" "` will just be converted to `""`.

Answer (score 2):

With at least PowerShell 7.2 and newer you can set a `ErrorMessage` value on a `ValidateScript` attribute.

```
  [ValidateScript(
    {![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_)},
    ErrorMessage = “null or whitespace”
  )]
```

More info on [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.4)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own `ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace` attribute, even in Windows PowerShell 5.1, you just need to create a [Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.4) that inherits from [`ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validateenumeratedargumentsattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0).

```bash
using namespace System.Management.Automation

class ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace : ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute {
    [void] ValidateElement([Object] $element) {
        if (-not [string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($element)) {
            return
        }

        throw [System.Management.Automation.MetadataException]::new(
            'The argument is null, empty, or consists of only white-space characters. ' +
            'Provide an argument that contains non white-space characters, and then try the command again.')
    }
}

function Test-Attribute {
    param([ValidateNotNullOrWhiteSpace()] $foo)
}

Test-Attribute '   '
```